# MySQL обновить поле в таблице

Tags: mysql, join

Имеется таблица `import_desc` с полями `sku` и `description`

Имеется таблица `os_product` с полями `product_id` и `sku`

Имеется таблица `os_product_description` с полями `product_id` и `description`

**Задача.** Обновить поле `description` в таблице `os_product_description` согласно данным из таблицы `import_desc`

У самого не получается правильно сjoinить таблицы и, соот-но, написать верный запрос.

**UPD.**

Таблица `import_desc`:

```
| sku | description         |
|-----|---------------------|
| 100 | Описание товара 100 |
| 101 | Описание товара 101 |
```

Таблица `os_product`:

```
| product_id | sku |
|------------|-----|
| pr000001   | 100 |
| pr000002   | 101 |
```

Таблица `os_product_description`:

```
| product_id | description  |
|------------|--------------|
| pr000001   | old desc 100 |
| pr000002   | old desc 101 |
```

Необходимо в таблице `os_product_description` поменять значения поля description на "Описание товара 100" и "Описание товара 101" соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE import_desc 
  JOIN os_product USING (sku)
  JOIN os_product_description USING (product_id)
SET os_product_description.description = import_desc.description
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d086d040519af16fe5ebc21442d376b)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, то, что мы делаем UPDATE таблицы import_desc, а обновляетм поле description в таблице os_product_description ничего старшного?

Comment: *то, что мы делаем UPDATE таблицы import_desc* С какого перепугу? мы обновляем все три таблицы. Т.е. формально `UPDATE (t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3) SET ...`

Comment: Ну я не силен в запрос MySQL, поэтому и спросил. Спасибо. Завтра буду пробовать.

Comment: @slota Fiddle добавлен в ответ.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!

Comment: Запрос выполняется очень долго. В таблицах os_product и os_product_description по 100.000 записей. Может есть варианты оптимизации запроса?

Comment: @slota Ну эта... индексы надо создать соответствующие.